# How to check a process is running in which core?

Tags: linux, process, scheduling, htop

I have a very computationally intensive job(single threaded) running in my system, and htop is showing one of the core is ~100%  utilized. Obviously, the job is scheduled to this core. But, I am wondering, is there any way to verify this?